# Convert Python calculator to PHP

Tags: php, python, calculator

Just for fun, I am trying to take the python calculator program written below and convert it to PHP.

Can anyone help me out/ is this possible?

The program is below and I want to get the same output by but with PHP.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
#title: calculator.py
#author: Samuel Peppard
#purpose:
#

# 1 equates a loop, everything else does not.
loop = 1 

# Contains the player's choice
choice = 0 

while loop == 1:

# Print what options you have
print " "
print "Basic Calculator Program!"

print " "
print "Select your function by typing its designated number..."

print " "
print "1) Addition"
print "2) Subtraction"
print "3) Multiplication"
print "4) Division"
print "5) Quit"
print " "

# allows for raw input to be read
choice = int(raw_input("Choose your option: ").strip())

if choice == 1:
    add1 = input("Add this amount: ")
    add2 = input("to this amount: ")
    print " "
    print add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2

elif choice == 2:
    sub2 = input("Subtract this amount: ")
    sub1 = input("from this amount: ")
    print " "
    print sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1 - sub2

elif choice == 3:
    mul1 = input("Multiply this amount: ")
    mul2 = input("with this amount: ")
    print " "
    print mul1, "*", mul2, "=", mul1 * mul2

elif choice == 4:
    div1 = input("Divide this amount: ")
    div2 = input("by this amount: ")
    print " "
    print div1, "/", div2, "=", div1 / div2

elif choice == 5:
    loop = 0

print "Goodbye for now!"
```

Comment: The program is missing everything pythonic, so a conversion should be no problem.

Comment: The only tricky bit might be you probably need `fgets(STDIN)` if you plan to use it on the command line, the rest is... well... basic as a basic calculator can be... Start coding ;)

Comment: Just for fun? It look like you're trying to get someone else to do the work for you?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, I just want to know if this is possible before I take it on.

Comment: Is that what I asked relentless?

Comment: Yes, it is what you asked. " **Can anyone help me out** / is this possible?"

Comment: Those words do not literally translate to "Do my work for me" even if this was "work". You have a right to be skeptical but I am just asking a question.

Comment: Thanks to Eric my question was answered perhaps I will think my question better next time.

Comment: THis is the typical i-am-an-idiot-and-please-do-my-work question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your second question:

> is this possible?

Of course it is. Both PHP and python are turing complete, and both can take console input.

Comment: [A bunch of rocks](http://xkcd.com/505/) can also be moved in a "turing complete" manner ..